# MQSUB ended with reason code 2429 in pub sub

Tags: c, ibm-mq, publish-subscribe

I am using IBM WebSphere MQ to set up a durable subscription for Pub/Sub. I am using their C APIs. I have set up a subscription name and have `MQSO_RESUME` in my options.

When I set a wait interval for my subscriber and I properly close my subscriber, it works fine and restarts fine.

But if I force crash my subscriber (Ctrl-C) and I try to re open it, I get a `MQSUB ended with reason code 2429` which is `MQRC_SUBSCRIPTION_IN_USE.`

I use `MQWI_UNLIMITED` as my `WaitInterval` in my `MQGET` and use `MQGMO_WAIT | MQGMO_NO_SYNCPOINT | MQGMO_CONVERT` as my `MQGET` options

This error pops up only when the topic has no pending messages for that subscription. If it has pending messages that the subscription can resume, then it resumes and it ignores the first published message in that topic

I tried changing the heartbeat interval to 2 seconds and that didn't fix it.

How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the queue manager has not yet detected that your application has lost its connection to the queue manager. You can see this by issuing the following MQSC command:-

```
DISPLAY CONN(*) TYPE(ALL) ALL WHERE(APPLTYPE EQ USER)
```

and you will see your application still listed as connected. As soon as the queue manager notices that your process has gone you will be able to resume the subscription again. You don't say whether your connection is a locally bound connection or a client connection, but there are some tricks to help speed up the detection of connections depending on the type of connection.

You say that in the times when you are able to resume you don't get the first message, this is because you are retrieving this messages with `MQGMO_NO_SYNCPOINT`, and so that message you are not getting was removed from the queue and was on its way down the socket to the client application at the time you forcibly crashed it, and so that message is gone. If you use `MQGMO_SYNCPOINT`, (and `MQCMIT`) you will not have that issue.

You say that you don't see the problem when there are still messages on the queue to be processed, that you only see it when the queue is empty. I suspect the difference here is whether your application is in an `MQGET`-wait or processing a message when you forcibly crash it. Clearly, when there are no messages left on the queue, you are guarenteed with the use of `MQWL_UNLIMITED`, to be in the `MQGET`-wait, but when processing messages, you probably spend more time out of the `MQGET` than in it.

You mention tuning down the heartbeat interval, to try to reduce the time frame, this was a good idea. You said it didn't work. Please remember that you have to change it at **both** ends of the channel, or you will still be using the default 5 minutes.

Comment: I have a client connection. 
I figured its that much. But, this is specifically for cases when my program crashes. In this case, normally we have a job which automatically brings up crashed processes immediately. Waiting for the queue manager to clean itself up would take time. What I want is a way to close the orphan subscription from my C code.

Comment: Btw, I use `MQWI_UNLIMITED` as my `WaitInterval` in my `MQGET` and use `MQGMO_WAIT | MQGMO_NO_SYNCPOINT | MQGMO_CONVERT` as my MQGET options

Comment: How long do you see it taking for the queue manager to notice the connection has gone?

Comment: around 5 minutes. I tried changing the heartbeat interval to 2 seconds and that didn't fix it.

Comment: Another thing I noticed is, this error pops up only when the topic has no pending messages for that subscription. 
If it has pending messages that the subscription can resume, then it resumes and it ignores the first published message in that topic.

Comment: Added more to the answer and moved your comments information into your question. If you like you can edit and delete your comments so everything you need to say is in there.

Comment: Changing to `MQGMO_SYNCPOINT` and using `MQCMIT` after every read fixed the problem with not getting the first message. 
But for the `2429` error, I am on a `MQ client` to `MQ server` connection and there was only server connection channel and no end channel.

Comment: There are always two channels, sometimes the CLNTCONN isn't obvious though. How are you providing your IP address and port number for the client app to use? set MQSERVER perhaps?

Comment: I have a `TAB` file I use to establish the connection. I don't have access to the settings, trying to get them.

Comment: The TAB file contains your CLNTCONN Channel, to lower the HBINT you will need to get that edited.